# Thread limit per session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have an aspx page which loads 10 charts asynchronously through Jquery Ajax requests. The requests are being made to Generic Handlers which implement IReadOnlySessionState since access to a session variable is required but it is a read and this way I am not affected by the read write session lock that asp.net implements.

Through the debugger I am able to see that calls are happening asynchronously but it seems that there is a limit as some of the calls are entering the code only after the first few have completed. I am not sure if this is by design on IIS or a property inside the web.config.

Is there a limit of threads that one user/session can have at one time?

Comment: where's limitation you are talking about at AJAX or at server. At server, since creating a new thread is costly, threads are picked up from thread pool which i guess has limitaion of 25 threads. If you are talking about browser(AJAX request), that should be dependent upon implementation of any perticular browser

Comment: There is a property called as ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads which you can explore

Comment: As I understand the browsers have limit of concurrent request sent to the server. I am not able to find the link, will post it as soon as I grab it.

Comment: The requests are leaving the browser instantly i can see them on a sniffer, its around 10 requests at once I am not exceeding the 25. The bottleneck seems to be at the webserver/iis. I tried setting the max pool size but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you check, if the bottleneck isn't the hardware itself. Depending on which Async/Task/Thread - Framework you are using, .Net might stop running new tasks, if the CPU is fully utilized

Comment: Thats the funny part cpu is barely breaking a sweat (not even 5%) and there is ample memory available (Over 2 GB).

Comment: @zahorak I highly doubt 2 web requests are completely utilizing the web server's resources.  It does seem much more likely that it's a per-user throttling limit to limit DOSing or otherwise having a single user consume an excessive amount of system resources.  That said, I wouldn't know how to determine if that's the case, or how to change the limits.

Comment: This is what I am guessing there is some inbuilt functionality to protect against a DOS attack. Or at least I am hoping, so that it is just an easy change to some value.

Comment: Are you running it on a server or desktop version of Windows?

Comment: Right now I am on Windows 7 Ultimate, this is where I am debugging. I have also tried it on Windows Server 2008. The time it takes to complete all of the requests is very similar

Answer (score 0):

The way IIS and asp.net handles threads depends on the version of IIS you are using.  There is a limit to the number of workerthreads and there are caps on the number of threads that must be left available.  This means that only a certain number of threads can execute at once.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx

> If your ASP.NET application is using web services (WFC or ASMX) or
>   System.Net to communicate with a backend over HTTP you may need to
>   increase connectionManagement/maxconnection.  For ASP.NET
>   applications, this is limited to 12 * #CPUs by the autoConfig feature.

Also from the same article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268

If you have long running HTTP requests from AJAX your best bet is to do asynchronous http request handlers.  Then the requests can be waiting on an IO thread, since asp.net has a lot more IO threads than workerthreads.

See: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45

Comment: I don't think this is related, also I am using .net 3.5 sorry forgot to mention it. Thanks though!

Comment: Which version of IIS your using?

Comment: I have it on IIS 7, on integrated mode.

Comment: As mentioned in the above blog, with IIS 6.0, there is possibility of having only few thread for application.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the thread pool maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU?

Comment: If you mean the Dword reg key value, yes I tried it yesterday. I set the value to 5000. I think I may have gotten it from the blog posted here

Comment: The post says there are about 10 grids loading asynchronously.  I've seen configurations that allow about 10-12 threads at a time.  Also, its not that straightforward to modify with latest versions of IIS, since there are multiple configs that you have to do.  It is more automated now.

Comment: How do you configure it to allow 10-12 threads at a time? Not sure I am following

Comment: I have been through all of the settings in the Machine.config and also found some keys you can change in the registry but still was not able to get it. I think I might just have to end up grouping a few of the calls together in order to try and get it to work better.